# Memories triggered by everything

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, memory, abnormal-psychology

I have this property of mind where memories of every event which is slightly more important than everyday routine gets linked with apparently anything that's existing or happening at that time and place.

For example talking about something important with someone while watching television would link that memory with whatever show was on tv and get recalled involuntarily every time the same show is watched.

Doing an action with a particular feeling in mind like fear , happiness , hate or hopelessness would tie that action with that feeling and the action would always trigger that feeling again.

The inverse is true as well like begin extremely happy suddenly reminds you of a particular person or event

Similar connections with feelings and  memories can be formed with a lot of things like smell , weather, temperature and even colour.

Is this quite common ? and is this recognised in cognitive sciences ? because I'm yet to meet someone with similar experiences.

Comment: It's interesting thanks for your explanation here,so what is specifically your question in brief?

Comment: @quintumnia the last paragraph. I.e is this something recognised in psychological or neuro science and is it a very common thing?

Comment: I have been reviewing your edit after the post has been on hold and unfortunately I cannot accept a re-opening of this post as it is still primarily asking a question on something which is affecting you cognitively.  Neither I or anyone else here is able to diagnose what your problem is without a thorough consultation and therefore cannot judge whether it is common or not.  I suggest you seek advice from a professional

Comment: I don't think the question is salvageable since it is simply too broad and involves both attention and memory in general and specific cases. In brief, what you are experiencing is contextual associative memories ( or unconscious knowledge )which we all experience through a spectrum mediated by attention as well as emotional state, cognitive science (gazzaniga) is a good place for an overview (Memory and attention).

Comment: @Allahjane what you're describing is something that i experience but to a far lesser extent. there is a well-characterised biological basis for it but the phenomenology of what you are describing suggests it is more ampilified in you. perhaps if you are troubled by it, you may be able to learn ways to adapt it to your benefit

Comment: @Chris I did not say it's a problem nor am I seeking medical help for it. All I am looking for is to know how normal or common it is and if it's known by a specific term. Please do not take this as medical help seeking.